# Closed bounded convex set in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: convex-analysis

Let the set $B \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be convex, bounded and closed. We want to show that set $B$ is equal to convex hull of its boundary?

Answer (score 1):

By [Krein-Milman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krein%E2%80%93Milman_theorem),
$$
B = \overline{\mathrm{conv}(\mathrm{ext}(B))}
\subseteq \overline{\mathrm{conv}(\partial(B))}
\subseteq \overline{\mathrm{conv}(B)}
= \overline{B} = B .
$$

Comment: Yes, I know that the asked question is **much** simpler, I'm just being lazy